# ember-simple-auth custom authenticator loses partial data on refresh

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth, torii

I have a custom authenticator which inherits from the torii authenticator:

https://github.com/wayne-o/sonatribe-ui/blob/master/app/authenticators/sonatribe-facebook.js

It works in so far as I can log in and I can see the session data in local storage:

`{"authenticator":"authenticator:custom","userId":"698671479","accessToken":"********","provider":"facebook-connect","user_id":"1111","user":{"slug":null,"name":null,"username":null,"profilePictureUrl":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p111x111/10325277_","auth":"1111","eventsAttending":[]}}`

However, upon refreshing most of the data has gone and I am left with:

`{"authenticator":"authenticator:custom","provider":"facebook-connect"}`

What part am i missing so that all of my session data is re-hydrated?

Comment: Make sure that `data` actually contains the full session data here: https://github.com/wayne-o/sonatribe-ui/blob/master/app/authenticators/sonatribe-facebook.js#L16

Comment: @marcoow 
 
It doesn't - how can I get it so that it does?  where would I pull that from? I thought that by this point we had the cut down JSON in local storage?

Comment: @marcoow how am I looking? https://github.com/wayne-o/sonatribe-ui/blob/master/app/authenticators/sonatribe-facebook.js seems to be working like a charm :) can you just validate i am doing it right please?